# How to apply/choose getPlanCache() and hint() depending on different situation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I already read official documentation to get the basic idea on getPlanCache() and hint().

- getPlanCache()

Displays the cached query plans for the specified query shape.

The query optimizer only caches the plans for those query shapes that can have more than one viable plan.

Official Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/PlanCache.getPlansByQuery/

- hint()

The $hint operator forces the query optimizer to use a specific index to fulfill the query. Specify the index either by the index name or by document.

Official Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/

**MyQuestion**

If I can make sure the specific collection can cache the plan, I don't need to use hint() to ensure optimized performance. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I already read official documentation to get the basic idea on getPlanCache() and hint().

To be clear: these are troubleshooting aids for investigating query performance. The MongoDB [query planner](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/) chooses the most efficent plan available based on a measure of "work" involved in executing a given query shape. If there is only a single viable plan, there is no need to cache the plan selection. If there are multiple query plans available for the same query shape, the query planner will periodically evaluate performance and update the cached plan selection if appropriate.

The [query plan cache methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-plan-cache/) allow you to inspect and clear information in the plan cache. Generally you would only want to clear the plan cache while investigating issues in a development/staging environment as this could have a noticeable affect on a busy deployment.

> If I can make sure the specific collection can cache the plan, I don't need to use hint() to ensure optimized performance. Is that correct?

In general you should avoid using `hint` (outside of testing query plans) as this bypasses the query planner and forces use of the hinted index even if there might be a more efficient index available.

If a specific query is not performing as expected, [`explain()` output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#explain-output) is the best starting point for insight into the query planning process.  If you're not sure how to optimise a specific query, I'd suggest posting a question on [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb) including the output of `explain(true)` (verbose explain) and your MongoDB server version.

For a helpful presentation, see: [Reading the .explain() Output - Charlie Swanson](https://explore.mongodb.com/vidyard-all-players/mongodb-world-presentations-crystal-c-charlie-swanson-6-20-2017-2) (June 2017).